# Automatically create a value for every User in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created A User Login And register Android App.  I used Firebase Auth For User Register. I want that when an user Register A counter value will be added to my database For that user. It will be created for all user. Counter Value Will be "0".

Comment: Hi Muntasir. That seems nice. What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` is something you need. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

```
FirebaseAuth fa = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

fa.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() { 

    @Override
    onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth auth) {
        //not sure how to check for the login event. but this should work too
        FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser()
        if(currentUser != null) {
            //add your data in your database.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear Rockernaap, I want that when  a user registration is successful then a name and value will be added to my firebase database for that user.Name will be Points And Value will be "0".

Answer (score 0):

I think firebase cloud functions would work great for this. Could you have a look at the [authentication triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events)?

Your nodeJS code would something like this, have a look at the getting started section [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

`exports.incrementUserount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  // increment the counter in the database here
});`

Comment: Would U Plz Explain It? Or Write The Code As I need?

Comment: Its javascript code, have a look at the getting started section and you should be able to do it yourself :D If you really cannot do it I will write it for you, but its really super straight forward and all the code you need is in the documentation.

Comment: i can do it but i want that u plz write  down the code .. Thanks In Advance :D

Comment: @MuntasirAonik I will have a look into it later today, but basically you want a user counter. Correct?

Comment: I want that when user registration is successful a Name and Value will be added to my database. Name Will be Points and Value Will be 0.